# An Integral involved $L^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Define, $$g_n :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \, ,$$ such that $g(x) = n$ on $\left[0, \dfrac{1}{n^3}\right]$ and $0$ otherwise.

I need to prove that, if $f \in L^2[0,1] ,$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f g_n \, d\mu = 0$

My attempt:

My idea is to use MCT.

$g \to 0$ pointwise a.e. Since $f \in L^2[0,1]$, $|f|^2 \in L^1[0,1]$, though it seems that this approach doesn't work since there is no $f^2$ to work with. Alternatively, can I use $L^2[0,1] \subset L^2[0,1]$?.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Cauchy Schwarz yields $$\left|\int g_n f\right|\leq \|g_n\|_{L^2}\|f\|_{L^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\|f\|_{L^2}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to use MCT here?

Comment: Obviously not because $fg_n$ is not uniformly bounded by an $L^2$ function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Hölders Inequality to estimate
$$||fg_{n}||_{L^1} \le ||f||_{L^2} \cdot ||g_{n}||_{L^2}$$

What can you say about the second factor?